# Apache poi POILogger exception

Tags: exception, apache-poi

I am getting the below error while converting xlsx file to csv using Apache poi. I have checked and I am using all 4.1.0 jar. Which jar should I specifically check for this issue?

```
Caught throwable Found class org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but interface was expected
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.apache.poi.util.POILogger, but interface was expected
```

Comment: The full stack trace would tell you the exact code line where the error is thrown. Then you would know what you specifically should check for this issue. But without having the full stack trace no help possible.

Comment: Looks like you have an older copy of Apache POI on your classpath, see http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10006 for help with tracking down the POI jar you didn't know you had!

Comment: Thank you, it was because of an older version of poi-3.15.jar. I replaced it with poi-4.1.jar to resolve the issue.